# how to poll server and check for updates

Tags: c#

i have this code which does GET from server and retrieves JSON.

```
private async void JSON_click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)

    { 
       var client=new HttpClient();
       client.MaxResponseBufferSize=1024*1024;
       var response= await Client.GetAsync(new Uri(The URL here));
       var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

       var component=JsonObject.Parse(result);

    }
```

I need to poll server for every 30 seconds to check for updates and retrieve the JSON. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe take a look on SignalR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Timer` with 30second interval and attach a callback function to retrieve JSON.

```
public void InitTimer()
{
    timer.Elapsed += new EventHandler(GetJSON);
    timer.Interval = 30000; //30sec*1000microsec             
    timer.Enabled = true;                       
    timer.Start();
}

void GetJSON(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Steps to retrieve JSON
}
```